# Scraping html with urls from website

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm scraping some html from a webite using php simple html dom, which include several images.
 However the images is not pointing correctly to the website. For example below is a example of one of the images where you can see it is no pointing to the website.
 Is it possible to dynamically change the urls to point to the website for instance

```
http://www.url.com/bilder/flags_long/United States.gif
```

html example

```
<img src="/bilder/flags_long/United States.gif" align="absmiddle" title="United States" alt="United States" border="0">
```

sample code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$sum_gosu = file_get_html("http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/news/30995-starladder-is-back-with-the-thirteenth-edition-of-starseries");
$gosu_full = $sum_gosu->find("//div[@class='content light']/div[@class='text clearfix']/div", 0);
```

Comment: you can join two texts together. I mean the website URL and the image URL. `$URL=$PageURL.$IMGsrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about concatenating the actual URL you fetched the document from and the relative image paths. Just to give an idea (this is not tested and you should definitely do some checks whether the image src attribute is relative or maybe absolute in some cases):

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.url.com/';
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $images = array();

    foreach($html->find('img') as $img) {

        // Option 1: Fill your images array (in case you only need the images)
        $images[] = rtrim($url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($img->src, '/');

        // Option 2: Update $img->src inside your $html document
        $img->src = rtrim($url, '/') . '/' . ltrim($img->src, '/');

    }

?>
```

**UPDATE** According your sample code my example could look like follows:

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $sum_gosu_url = "http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/news/30995-starladder-is-back-with-the-thirteenth-edition-of-starseries";
    $sum_gosu = file_get_html($sum_gosu_url);
    $gosu_full = $sum_gosu->find("//div[@class='content light']/div[@class='text clearfix']/div", 0);

    foreach($gosu_full->find('img') as $img) {
        $img->src = $sum_gosu_url . $img->src;
    }
?>
```

After that the img src attributes inside your $gosu_full document should be fixed and resolvable (downloadable by a client). Hope that helps and that I'm actually understanding your problem :)

Comment: What i meant was that i have a long string which contain lots of html tags, but also images. These images i would like to change to the right path if they dont work

Comment: So where does the string actually come from? Is it a file on your web server or is it a page you fetched from a remote URL? Because you definitely need to know with which URL you have to prefix the relative paths of your images which would in first case be your own domain and in the second case the domain you fetched the html document from. Sorry when I'm mistaken but that's what I understood :)

Comment: In case I'm wrong please post some sample code how you load your html string.

Comment: Can i remove a image by passing $img = ""; inside the loop?

Comment: I think you could have a try with `unset($img)` and I could imagine the simple-html-dom library will unset it appropriately but I haven't had a closer look to their implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
$url="http://www.url.com";
$Chtml = file_get_html($url);
$imgurl=Chtml->find("img",0)->src;
echo $url.$imgurl;
```

Comment: Nice !  Some basic explanations on the code and how it answers the question would be very helpful.